# group_by or distinct with postgres/dbix-class

Tags: postgresql, dbix-class

I have a posts table like so:

```
+-----+----------+------------+------------+
|  id | topic_id |    text    |  timestamp |
+-----+----------+------------+------------+
| 789 |     2    |     foobar | 1396026357 |
| 790 |     2    |     foobar | 1396026358 |
| 791 |     2    |     foobar | 1396026359 |
| 792 |     3    |     foobar | 1396026360 |
| 793 |     3    |     foobar | 1396026361 |
+-----+----------+------------+------------+
```

How would I could about "grouping" the results by topic id, while pulling the most recent record (sorting by timestamp desc)?

I've come to the understanding that I might not want "group_by" but rather "distinct on".  My postgres query looks like this:

```
select distinct on (topic_id) topic_id, id, text, timestamp 
from posts 
order by topic_id desc, timestamp desc;
```

This works great.  However, I can't figure out if this is something I can do in DBIx::Class without having to write a custom ResultSource::View.  I've tried various arrangements of group_by with selects and columns, and have tried distinct => 1.  If/when a result is returned, it doesn't actually preserve the uniqueness.

Is there a way to write the query I am trying through a resultset search, or is there perhaps a better way to achieve the same result through a different type of query?

Comment: Aside: *never* use basic type names like `text` or `timestamp` as identifier.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  Sometimes certain things are out of one's control, and "never" or "always" doing something isn't a matter of choice.  Thankfully I am able to wrap col names in double quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the section in the DBIC Cookbook on [grouping results](http://search.cpan.org/~ribasushi/DBIx-Class-0.08270/lib/DBIx/Class/Manual/Cookbook.pod#Grouping_results).

I believe what you want is something along the lines of this though:

```
my $rs = $base_posts_rs->search(undef, {
    columns  => [ {topic_id=>"topic_id"}, {text=>"text"}, {timestamp=>"timestamp"} ],
    group_by => ["topic_id"],
    order_by => [ {-desc=>"topic_id"}, {-desc=>"timestamp"} ],
})
```

Edit:  A quick and dirty way to get around strict SQL grouping would be something like this:

```
my $rs = $base_posts_rs->search(undef, {
    columns  => [
        { topic_id  => \"MAX(topic_id)" },
        { text      => \"MAX(text)" },
        { timestamp => \"MAX(timestamp)" },
    ],
    group_by => ["topic_id"],
    order_by => [ {-desc=>"topic_id"}, {-desc=>"timestamp"} ],
})
```

Of course, use the appropriate aggregate function for your need.

Comment: Thanks.  I did go to the cookbook initially, and doing like above runs me into the "must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function" error, which I've read is a result of postgres not supporting selection by ungrouped columns:  
  
    "When GROUP BY is present, it is not valid for the SELECT list expressions to refer to ungrouped columns except within aggregate functions, since there would be more than one possible value to return for an ungrouped column."  
  
I attempted to add in the other columns to the group clause, but this results in non-uniqueness.

Comment: You can check my revised answer to a method that may work for you.

Comment: I'm able to get the results as expected with this with some syntax adjustments, though I wonder if this will lead to a grouped result having field values from across the grouped items as a result of the different aggregate functions on each selected field.  It looks to work for my purposes for the moment though.  Much thanks.